# Repeat keras (tensorflow) model over additional dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Let's say I have a model that maps a tensor with shape [n, 10] to a tensor with shape [n, 2] where n is the batch size. How can I repeat the model so that the resulting model accepts an input tensor with shape [n, k, 10] and outputs a tensor with shape [n, k, 2]? The k versions of the model should share all weights.

Comment: heya, you need to add a bit more detail in the question, maybe a code sample etc. Have a look into the guide of how to write a good question for more details https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I thought about it and decided against it as any possibility based on a keras.Model object would be fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
input_ = Input((k, model.input.shape[1]))
input_as_list = Lambda(lambda x: tf.unstack(x, axis=1))(input_)
model_outputs = [model(x) for x in input_as_list] 
model_outputs = [Lambda(lambda x: K.expand_dims(x, axis=1))(y) for y in model_outputs]
concat_output = Concatenate(axis=1)(model_outputs)
new_model = Model(input_, concat_output)
```

Comment: Exactly what I asked for :) Thanks!

Comment: The downside of this solution is that you won't benefit from model parallelization, don't you?
Say that the model is very simple (like one dense layer), but that the input list is big : the graph will get overly complicated with many repetition of the same element, and thye would be computed one after another... Isn't there any better solution? Like changing batch size (multiply it by N) of the sub model in order to have it accept more vectors?